# Eclipse update failure - ADT 22 installed ok but SDK cant be updated to 22 afterwards

Tags: android, eclipse

"Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/:80 refused"

But it's the same for others also like:

"Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/:80 refused"

Happens when trying to update from SDK v21 to v22. I have already installed ADT 22(double checked).

What should my http proxy server be? I have dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
and ticked the box "Force https.....http"

I changed http proxy server to to:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml
and now it completes without errors but doesn't upgrade to v22.

I tried turning off my firewall and VPN(I am in mainland China today) and it's the same.

Comment: Have you successfully updated the sdk before on this machine? I ask to avoid telling things you've already tried!

Comment: Yes, I've updated at least once before. However, feel free to treat me like it's my first time, since I haven't updated in a while, nor often.

Comment: Sometimes I can only update the sdk from the SDKManager directly, as opposed to running the SDK manager from inside eclipse. I think it's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Comment: It's odd. When I run this, I get a version 20 instead of 21 or 22. It also wont update. I think I will reinstall from scratch.

Comment: Have you given it permission to install things? there's a windows setting it may need ...

Comment: might be bcoz of proxy setting...whats ur proxy server and port

Comment: Um, no proxy, I think? From home. I ran as administrator so no permission issues running from c:\program files.......

Comment: Even after fresh download I had the same issue. I surrendered and downloaded sdk platforms from: http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html  . Can anyone give me any more suggestions before I close this???

Answer (score 0):

My environment is Win7(64 bit), jdk 1.6.0_14(32 bit)

Add the following line into the end of the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:
74.125.237.1        dl-ssl.google.com

Comment: Please comment it more.